# USB hard drive doesn't auto mount

Tags: automounting

I just bought a Raspberry Pi and want to start using it as a NAS. 
I'm fairly new to this, but I've gotten this far.

I've got an external hard drive (freshly formatted NTFS) connected with a USB cable to my Raspberry Pi and am connected through SSH terminal (I don’t have an external display to use).
Every time my Pi reboots, I have to remount the drive in order to use it. 
I added this line to `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/dev/sda1   /media/NAS      ntfs-3g    defaults 0       0
```

For as far as I understand, that’s all I need to make my Raspberry Pi auto mount my USB hard drive as soon as it reboots.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does running `mount /media/NAS` manually work? What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should try. First is to change the last `0` on that
line to `1` or `2` as you only want this mounted once your root file system (which normally is at level `0`) has been mounted, as that is probably where `/media/NAS` is located.

Then you might also need to remove the `-3g` IIRC, that was dropped from `ntfs` a couple of years ago after the third generation became the "standard' version.

```
/dev/sda1   /media/NAS      ntfs    auto,defaults   0   2
```

Comment: Hi,I tried it with changing the last `0` to `1` or `2`, but no avail, I removed the `-3` behind NTFS, but that didn't automount it either.
I'm at work now and I think my hard drive is turned off, so I'm gonna have to try it out when I'm back at home. (thanks for the quick response)

Comment: @Dutchman I had the chance to try this out remotely on a friends Banana Pi, (running a Debian derivative, he lives 550km away and had bought a 6Tb external drive). After that I realise I did not remove the `noauto`, option but changed it to `auto` for him. Which I thought would be included in the default, but you can try to add it explicitly (as I did). If that doesn't work: Q1) does `mount /media/NAS` work? or do you mount differently. And Q2) what distribution are you running on your raspberry pi?

Comment: OTOH `defaults` should include `auto`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work using the fstab file, so I ended up writing a mount script `sudo mount UUID=44C0BAFAC0BAF172 /data`, and referenced to it in the /etc/rc.local file. Once rebooted I was able to access the drive immediately. Q1 I usually mount with `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /folder-to-mount-in` or `sudo mount -a`. Q2 Raspbian

Comment: @Dutchman does that mean you never tested just using `mount /media/NAS`? Maybe your `/dev/sda1` is not that drive, or your usb module is not loaded at that point yet. You can use UUID as with  `UUID=44C0BAFAC0BAF172 /data ntfs defaults 0 2` in the `/etc/fstab` as well.

Comment: I checked whether /dev/sda1 was the name of my drive with `sudo fdisk -l`. (by the way, `/media/NAS/` became `/data/` just a different mount folder). so `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /data` mounts the drive just fine. The problem is not that the drive doesn't want to mount, the problem is that it doesn't/didn't auto mount when I rebooted my pi. I also tried `UUID=44C0BAFAC0BAF172 /data ntfs defaults 0 2` in fstab, but that doesn't automount my drive when I reboot.